# How to get URL from firebase storage?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I have the following code:

```
const imgURL = () => {
        const fileName = report.reporter.avatar.Pc.path.segments[8];
        const storageRef = storage.ref('images');
        storageRef.child(`/${fileName}`).getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
            console.log(url) // here I am getting the url in the console
            return url;
        });
    }

    console.log(imgURL()); // here its undefiend
```

for some how I dont know why I cant get what the function return

Comment: My problem is inside the function.. when i console log from the function scope i do get the url. but when i console log the function to get what it returns i am getting undifeind

Comment: Shouldn't there a  `return` before `storageRef.child`?

Comment: I did. then i get strange object with the url inside "i" paramneter. how do i get that? I get D object with "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i" parameters. "i" is undifeind but when i click on the object "i" is the url i want. so how do i get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this with `async` / `await` i don't know if `async` / `await` works for react.

```
const imgURL = async () => {
    const fileName = report.reporter.avatar.Pc.path.segments[8];
    const storageRef = storage.ref('images');
    const url = await storageRef.child(`/${fileName}`).getDownloadURL().catch((error) => { throw error });;
    return url;
}
```

change your calling method with this :

```
console.log(await imgURL());
```

Comment: its giving me a promise pending

Answer (score 1):

that what fixed my code (useState)

```
 const [avatarUrl, setAvatarUrl] = useState('');

    const imgURL = async () => {
        const fileName = report.reporter.avatar.Pc.path.segments[8];
        const storageRef = storage.ref('images');
        await storageRef.child(`/${fileName}`).getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
            setAvatarUrl(url);
        });
    }
    imgURL();
```